# Not able to access internet from optimized Ubuntu 18.04.1 on Hyper-V

Tags: networking, internet

I created an Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS VM using Hyper-V Quick Create on Windows 10 Pro Version 1803.  It seems to have worked except I am not able to access websites with http.  Name resolutions seem to be working fine.  I am able to ping addresses, but accessing websites with Firefox always times out.

Ping:

[image: ping capture]

When I attempt to telnet to port 80:

[image: telnet capture]

My network connection icon shows as a question mark:

[image: network icon capture]

My wired connection details:

[image: Wired settings]

Answer (score 0):

It seems likely that the IP addresses are being used by multiple systems. For example, if you're using a static IP address on multiple machines.

Comment: @krisives - Not sure how this could be the case.  I don't believe I'm using static IPs.  Ubuntu is running as VM on top of Windows 10 and I believe somehow uses NAT to allow Ubuntu network access through the Windows NIC.  I can access the internet fine from Windows 10.

Comment: Are you running multiple VMs?

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/515391/unable-to-connect-to-internet-on-hyper-v-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: No. I've created two VMs in an effort to resolve, but only running one currently.

Comment: @krisives - I tried every variation of the solution in your link that I could think of.  I tried both bridging my WiFi and my Ethernet connections.  I tried bridging newly created virtual switch as well as the out-of-the-box "Default Switch".  Bridging my WiFi while Windows was using Ethernet produced same result, can ping but cannot telnet to port 80.  Bridging Ethernet insted of my WiFi connection resulted in Windows losing connectivity and Ubuntu not being able to start the interface.

Comment: I don't use Hyper-V but VirtualBox instead and don't have this problem, but I can tell you that it's something to do with Hyper-V or your networking configuration because your `ping` command shows that google.com is resolving to an IP address within that subnet, which is incorrect.

Comment: I agree both my local IP and the resolved google.com IP address begin with 172 but the IP address for google.com is not on my local subnet.  If I ping google.com from Windows 10 (the host) I get same IP address.  I do not understand why ping works but I cannot access any addresses over port 80.  I've been using VirtualBox but I'd like to switch to Hyper-V as I think it will be faster and VirtualBox conflicts with Docker as Docker (on Windows 10) requires that Hyper-V be enabled.  Thank you for your ideas.  I really want this to work.

Comment: Turns out the reason I was not able to access the internet was due to Symantec Endpoint Protection (SEP) software installed on my Windows 10 host.  SEP was blocking external access to all ports on my Windows 10 host and SEP was seeing my VM as external.  Since I am running this on my employer provided laptop I would have to make a strong case for running a unique SEP policy.  I switched back to using VirtualBox and do not have this problem.  Drawback is Ubuntu runs slower on VirtualBox than Hyper-V.